# The DateTime, setTime method is jumping forward one hour, whats going on?

Tags: php, datetime

Ok I have a function that counts the number of working hours between two dates and returns the time in minuets. Working Hours are between 08:30 and 17:30 excluding weekends.

This seems to be working fine on my development machine but when I put it on the live server for some reason the settime method jumps forward one hour in the middle of a loop.

Here is the code

```
$onHoldStart = '2014-10-07 17:09:00';
$onHoldEnd = '2014-10-08 14:36:18';
$onHoldHours = biss_hours($onHoldStart, $onHoldEnd);

echo $onHoldHours.'<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br />';

system('date +%Z');


/**
 * Counts the number of working hours between two given dates
 * E.g. Hours between 08:30 and 17:30 excluding weekends.
 * Takes start date and end date (Y-m-d H:i:s)
 * 
 */
function biss_hours($start, $end){
    $logfile='customlog.log';
    $log='';
    $log .='raw start '.$start."\n";
    $startDate = new DateTime($start);
    $log .= 'start '. $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";

    //date time period starts counting from the same hour so add hour to start to compensate
    $startDate->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
    $endDate = new DateTime($end);
    $periodInterval = new DateInterval( "PT1H" );

    $period = new DatePeriod( $startDate, $periodInterval, $endDate );
    $count = 0;

    foreach($period as $date){
        $log .= 'DATE '. $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
        $startofday = clone $date;
        $startofday->setTime(8,30);
        $log .= 'start of day '. $startofday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
        $endofday = clone $date;
        $endofday->setTime(17,30);

        if($date > $startofday && $date <= $endofday && !in_array($date->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday'))){
            $count++;
        }
    }
    $log .='count '.$count;
    $test = file_put_contents($logfile, $log);
    return ($count * 60) + biss_minutes($start, $end);

}


function biss_minutes($start, $end){
    $diff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
    $in = intval(date('i',$diff));
    return $in;
}
```

As you can see this code also adds a log file, the log file shows the discrepancy I am talking about.

Log file from my local machine:

```
raw start 2014-10-07 17:09:00
start of day 2014-10-07 08:30:00
DATE 2014-10-07 19:09:00
start of day 2014-10-07 08:30:00
DATE 2014-10-07 20:09:00
start of day 2014-10-07 08:30:00
DATE 2014-10-07 21:09:00
(Skip a few)
count 6
```

Log file from the server:

```
 raw start 2014-10-07 17:09:00
 start 2014-10-07 17:09:00
 DATE 2014-10-07 18:09:00
 start of day 2014-10-07 08:30:00
 DATE 2014-10-07 19:09:00
 start of day 2014-10-07 09:30:00
 DATE 2014-10-07 20:09:00
 start of day 2014-10-07 09:30:00
 DATE 2014-10-07 21:09:00
 start of day 2014-10-07 09:30:00
 DATE 2014-10-07 22:09:00
 start of day 2014-10-07 09:30:00
 DATE 2014-10-07 23:09:00
 start of day 2014-10-07 09:30:00
 DATE 2014-10-08 00:09:00
 start of day 2014-10-08 09:30:00
 DATE 2014-10-08 01:09:00
 start of day 2014-10-08 09:30:00
 count 5
```

As you can see the 08:30:00 has suddenly became 09:30:00 after the first iteration of the loop. Why is this happening? Both servers are set to BST the current uk timezone.

The correct output should be

387
2014-10-08 16:32:47
BST

But because of this hour jump the server output is :

327
2014-10-08 16:33:16
BST

Removing 60 minuets.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: *"This seems to be working fine on my development machine but when I put it on the live server for some reason the settime method jumps forward one hour in the middle of a loop. "* - Server timezone differences?

Comment: try putting `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` at the top of your code and see if it works.

Comment: I like how you take credit for writing this function even though most of it came from SO answers to your questions.

Comment: *"As you can see the 08:30:00 has suddenly became 09:30:00 after the first iteration of the loop. Why is this happening?"* Because you're incrementing by an hour in each iteration.

Comment: I said I have a function I never said i wrote it! Also the server time zones are the same. Thats why im confused.

Comment: *"Written by andrew.mclaughlan@salesagility.com"*

Comment: Thats is just comment internally so other guys I work with know who the code came from

Comment: Does one server recognize daylight saving and the other doesn't.  It seem the palce where you are having this problem is `$startofday->setTime(8,30);`  I would be interested if your `$endofday->setTime(17,30);` also results in time shifting by an hour.

Comment: they both output bst which is British summer time e.g. UTC +1 Ill check the endofday.

Comment: Yep end of day is jumping forward one hour also. I still don’t see why it would jump when I am setting it to 8,30. There must be another setting in the php settings that is wrong.

Comment: Both server timezones in the php.ini are date.timezone = "Europe/London"

Comment: Could this be due to a bug in php?  My dev server is PHP version: 5.3.10-1 ubuntu3.14. But the live server is PHP version: 5.3.2-1 ubuntu4.27